# nodejs 6 supported os'es, windows server 2012

Tags: node.js

Been looking online for a list of supported operating systems for nodejs, but after version 4.0, there is no place to find this information.

Anyone knows where it can be found? In particular for windows 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, according to [this announcement](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.0.0/):

**Node is supported on Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, or higher.**

On https://nodejs.org/en/download/ both 32 and 64-bit versions are available.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868152/node-js-supported-operating-systems/40869223#40869223) for more details and links.